# Grease pencil lineart modifier does not appear through the image plane

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

An image plane acts as a barrier for the grease pencil lineart modifier as if it's an actual plane. Is there a way for the lineart modifier to pass through flat planes? Could there be an add-on perhaps??

The outline on a rectangle is actually an emission material with a solidify modifier. I had to do these manually for each object, but it doesn't have the same effect as the lineart modifier that outlines particular creases & edges. We're planning to put animated image sequences for our thesis animation as a final render, which is the dilemma we're facing right now.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ? You can delete everything else but the few objects concerned by your issue (be sure to save a *copy* of your blend file before deleting anything).

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can use the *Occlusion* parameter within the *Line Art Modifier*.

Within object properties of the grease pencil object, make sure the *In Front* parameter is checked off to activate the *Occlusion* parameter. Within the line art modifier, under *Occlusion*, select *Level* $1$.

[image]

Each level represents a layer of faces occluding/blocking the geometry you want to use to generate line art. Since you are only using a single *image plane*, only the first set of faces are obstructing the line art that you want to generate. Hence, why we would select *Level* $1$.

Personally, I would generate the occluded lines in a separate line art modifier stacked on the first so that it wouldn't interfere with the line art that has already generated.